# AWS Lambda logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using AWS Lambda behind API Gateway.

In my logs (coming from lambda), I have something like

```
Timestamp | Request received ...
Timestamp | Request received ...
Timestamp | Response sent statusCode=200 ...
Timestamp | Request received ...
Timestamp | Response sent statusCode=200  ...
Timestamp | Response sent statusCode=510  ...
Timestamp | Request received ...
Timestamp | Request received ...
Timestamp | Response sent statusCode=500  ...
Timestamp | Response sent statusCode=200  ...
```

Is there a way to trigger an alarm when "statusCode=500" occurs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a metric filter on a cloudwatch log group with the pattern you want similar to what's described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CountOccurrencesExample.html). The metric filter turns the log occurrences into a numerical cloudwatch metric. Once you have the cloudwatch metric, you can create an alarm based on it with the desired threshold and alarm action to trigger SNS topic to get your alarms.

**1. Create a metric filter:**

```
aws logs put-metric-filter \
  --log-group-name /aws/lambda/myfunction \
  --filter-name MyAppErrorCount \
  --filter-pattern 'statusCode=500' \
  --metric-transformations \
    metricName=ErrorCount,metricNamespace=MyNamespace,metricValue=1,defaultValue=0
```

**2. Create an SNS topic and get its arn(Amazon Resource Name).**

**3. Create an alarm based on the metric while specify the SNS topic arn to notify:**

Replace `<YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID>` with your AWS account id, `<TOPIC_NAME>` with your topic name, and other values like region in below command:

```
aws cloudwatch put-metric-alarm --alarm-name MyAppErrorAlarm \
 --metric-name ErrorCount \
 --namespace MyNamespace \
 --period 300 \
 --evaluation-periods 1 \
 --threshold 0 \
 --comparison-operator GreaterThanThreshold \
 --statistic Sum \
 --alarm-actions arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:<YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID>:<TOPIC_NAME>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think it would work so I accept it.
However, what I needed (and this was not clear in my question) was a  notification for each error (with the content of the log message)
I've since learned this can not be done with metrics so I have yet to come with something ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use cloud watch subscription filters to filter only for a matching regex pattern and then use SNS to send an alarm or notification (you will need addtional lambda consumer for send sns).

**Better approach**

Since the logs are generated by Lambda, it is better to publish the error codes as custom cloudwatch metrics from lambda code. Creating an alarm over the custom metrics will be the solution.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html